# Snape muttering his little counter curse

Tags: harry-potter

We know in *Harry Potter and the Sorceror's Stone* that Professor Quirrell was a supporter of Voldemort and had him in the back of his head (as a host).

Quirrell wanted to kill Harry with his curse, whilst trying to maintain eye contact in the Quidditch game, until Snape intervened "muttering his counter-course" and helping Harry.

**Why didn't Voldemort question Snape about this?**

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate. If it's not covered by the linked questions you can edit to explain why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Voldemort came back in *The Goblet of Fire*, he *did* end up asking Snape about it. Snape mentions this in the beginning of *The Half-Blood Prince*:

> “I think you next wanted to know,” he pressed on, a little more loudly, for Bellatrix showed every sign of interrupting, “why I stood between the Dark Lord and the Sorcerer’s Stone. That is easily answered. He did not know whether he could trust me. He thought, like you, that I had turned from faithful Death Eater to Dumbledore’s stooge. He was in a pitiable condition, very weak, 
>   sharing the body of a mediocre wizard. He did not dare reveal himself to a former ally if that ally might turn him over to Dumbledore or the Ministry. I deeply regret that he did not trust me. He would have returned to power three years sooner. As it was, I saw only greedy and unworthy Quirrell 
>   attempting to steal the stone and, I admit, I did all I could to thwart him.”
>   Bellatrix’s mouth twisted as though she had taken an unpleasant dose of medicine.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 2: "Spinner's End"</sub>

So it's not that Voldemort didn't become suspicious of Snape as a result of this, it's simply that Snape managed to convince Voldemort that he was unaware that it was the Dark Lord trying to get the Stone, or otherwise he would have helped him.